# Run POST API in loop

Tags: python-3.x

```
Import requests
Import json

Headers = {

      ‘Content-Type’: ‘application/json’
      ‘Accept’: ‘application/json’,
      ‘X-AUTH-TOKEN’: ‘API KEY’,
       }

data = ‘{“modelId”: “12345”, “cmdbId”: “11122222”}’

Response = requests.post(‘https://splunk/api/modelinfo/, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
```

---

Above code works fine for single Data.

Now, I have >10 line data in text file  as below and need to run the POST API in loop for each line.

```
modelId: 12345 cmdbId: 11122222
modelId: 12346 cmdbId: 11122223
modelId: 12347 cmdbId: 11122224
```

Comment: Your code appears to be formatted strangely. Can you post something we can run? For your question: what's stopping you from using a loop to execute one request per line in your file?

Comment: Thanks @N.Wouda. I manage to modify the code as below, but now only issue can see that the end point accepts the data value in single quotes, but in my code it is running without quotes and Response code 422 as error.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'X-AUTH-TOKEN': 'API KEY'
       }

payload = [
    {'modelId': 12345, 'cmdbId': 11122222},
    {'modelId': 12346, 'cmdbId': 11122223},
    {'modelId': 12347, 'cmdbId': 11122224}
    ]

for data in payload:
    response = requests.post("https://splunk/api/modelinfo/", headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
    if response.status_code in [200, 201, 204]:
        print("post successful")
```